# Making html-table work as an Excel document

Tags: html, excel, html-table, cell, calculated-columns

I'm working on an order form to a bookshop-website. It's just like a normal table in HTML and I wonder how to make a cell calculate other cell's value and display the sum of it. As it works in Excel.

Comment: You'll need to use JavaScript. I recommend a framework like jQuery (http://jquery.com/). In order to help with your specific problem, we're going to need a few specifics. Can you post some code?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the Google Spreadsheets API?

Comment: While that is certainly possible, you should either check out ready made e-commerce solutions and/or consider doing this server-side.

Answer (score 0):

I get order sheets like these all the time from my wholesale vendors. I personally don't offer this because I have multiple price points for my wholesale customers and I'd rather not manualy verify that the prices in the spreadsheet are in fact the price that they pay.  So I'd definately recommend that you do this server side ultimately.

I didn't know this until I just tried it, but you can actually just make a table with the literal Excel formulas in them. You can then either

1. ctrl+c it into a new spreadsheet.
2. Send it down as an Excel spreadsheet via something like ASP.Net Response.ContentType.
3. Change the extension to .xls.

I did this with this example html and it works:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Extended</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jasper's Jasper</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>$7.50</td>
            <td>=(B2*C2)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Widget</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>$2.10</td>
            <td>=(B3*C3)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2>Totals</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Total</td>
            <td>=SUM(D2:D3)</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: ...And now I think I see what you're asking, in which this is probably useless.  Oh well.